# Prove that there is at most one non-abelian group of order $28$ all of whose Sylow $2$-subgroups are cyclic

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, sylow-theory

Let $G$ be a non-abelian group of order $28$ all of whose Sylow $2$-subgroups are cyclic. Show that there is at most one such group (up to isomorphism).

By Sylow's theorems, $G$ has a unique (normal) Sylow $7$-subgroup $H$ and $7$ Sylow $2$-subgroups (call one of them $K\simeq Z_4$).  $K$ acts on $H$ by conjugation, which gives a homomorphism $f: Z_4\rightarrow Z_6$. There are 2 such homomorphisms: $f(1)=0,3$. I can't see what can I get from this. Is it a wrong way?

Comment: I think it would be clearer if you looked for homomorphisms $K \to {\rm Aut}(H)$. I know that ${\rm Aut}(H) \cong Z_6$, but that is not particularly helpful here. If $H = \langle x \rangle$, then the automorphisms of $H$ have the form $x \mapsto x^i$ for $1 \le i \le 6$.

Comment: @DerekHolt I thought about that (that's where $Z_6$ came from) but in any case I don't know how this can be helpful.

Comment: $f(1)=0$ corresponds to the trivial homomorphism. So you are done.

Answer (score 1):

As Derek Holt points out, it is better to regard $\mathrm{Aut}(H)\cong(\mathbb{Z}/7\mathbb{Z})^\times$, in which case the two possible homomorphisms $\mathbb{Z}/4\mathbb{Z}\to (\mathbb{Z}/7\mathbb{Z})^\times$ are $f(1)=1$ and $f(1)=6$ (i.e. $khk^{-1}=h$ or $khk^{-1}=h^6=h^{-1}$, where $K=\langle k\rangle$).

Suppose that $f(1)=1$. Then, $khk^{-1}=h$ for all $h\in H$ and $k\in K$ and, in turn, $hkh^{-1}=k$  for all $h\in H$ and $k\in K$. Therefore, $H\leq N_G(K)$. But,  $[G:N_G(K)]$ divides $4=[G:H]$ which is impossible since $[G:N_G(K)]=7$.

Finally, we must have $f(1)=6$, and $G\cong\langle h,k\mid h^7=k^4=1,\;kh=h^{-1}k\rangle$.

Comment: Thanks. I don't understand the normalizer argument. We know that the order of $G$ is the product of the order of $N_G(K)$ and the number of conjugate subgroups of $K$, i.e., 7. Shouldn't then $N_G(K)$  have order 4? Why is it 7? And why does it divide $[G:H]$?

Comment: $G$ acts on $K$ by conjugation. The size of the orbit (I.e. the number of Sylow 2-subgroups) equals the index of the stabilizer. The stabilizer is $N_G(K)$, so $7=[G:N_G(K)]$. Now, if $H\leq N_G(K)$ then $4=[G:H]=[G:N_G(K)][N_G(K):H]$. Hence 4|7, a contradiction.

Comment: Can I just say istead that $khk^{-1}=h$ implies that the elements of $K$ commute with those of $H$, and also $KH=G$, so $G$ must be abelian?

Also, it seems I don't understand why the orbit from your previous comment consists of Sylow 2-subgroups. This would be true if $G$ acted on the set of Sylow 2-subgroups, and not on some particular subgroup.

Comment: Yes, you are right. $G$ acts on the set of conjugates of $K$.

Answer (score 1):

By the counting argument, the $7$-Sylow subgroup $H$ is unique, hence normal. Moreover, said $K$ a $2$-Sylow subgroup, it is $H\cap K=1$. Therefore, any such a group arises as a nontrivial semidirect product $K\ltimes H$. Since $\operatorname {Aut}(H)\cong$ $\mathbb Z/6\mathbb Z$, if we prove that there is *at most* one nontrivial homomorphism $\varphi\colon \mathbb Z/4\mathbb Z\to \mathbb Z/6\mathbb Z$, then we are done. There are two options, only: $\ker\varphi$ is trivial or $\ker\varphi=\{0,2\}$. But the former is ruled out by Lagrange's theorem, as $4\nmid 6$. Therefore, *the only possible* option is that $0$ and $2$ are mapped to $0$, whereas $1,3$ (both of order $4$) are necessarily mapped to $3$, which is the only element of order $2$ in $\mathbb Z/6\mathbb Z$$^\dagger$. So, finally, there is *at most* one such a nontrivial homomorphism, namely *at most* one nonabelian group of order $28=2^27$ all of whose $2$-Sylow subgroups are cyclic.

(To prove that there is *precisely one* such a group, one should prove that the map singled out above is actually operation-preserving. That is true, but it goes beyond the scope of the question.)

---

$^{\dagger}$The order of the image of an element under a homomorphism divides the order of the element. And $\mathbb Z/6\mathbb Z$ hasn't got any element of order $4$.